# How to make data transition between table view cells with where button out of table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two custom table views. I need to pass first and second cell datas of DestinationTableView to first cell of MyCartTableView. How can I make transition between this two table view cells with outside of tableView.

I did `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` but this time I need to make with `UIButton`outside of tableView.

Below triggered with tableView cell.

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "cellForFoodSegue" {
        if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? DetailViewController
        {
            let indexPath = self.mainTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

            var foodNameArray: String
            var foodPriceArray: Double

            foodNameArray = foodNames[indexPath.row]
            foodPriceArray = foodPrices[indexPath.row].purchaseAmount

            destinationViewController.detailFoodName = foodNameArray
            destinationViewController.detailFoodPrice = foodPriceArray

        }

    }
}
```

I tried below code but I did not success passing data with button.

```
@IBAction func addBasket(_ sender: Any) {

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "addToCartSegue") {


        if let addToCartVC = segue.destination as? MyCartViewController {

            let selectedCell = sender as! UITableViewCell
            let indexPath = self.detailTableView.indexPath(for: selectedCell)

           var foodNameArray: String
           var foodPriceArray: Double

           foodNameArray = foodNames[indexPath.row]
           foodPriceArray = prices[indexPath.row].purchaseAmount

           addToCartVC.fromDetailFoodName = foodNameArray
            addToCartVC.fromDetailFoodPrice = prices[(indexPath?.row)!].purchaseAmount

        }
    }
}
```

Belows my MyViewController codes. Which is my added objects when tapped to `addBasket` button

```
class MyCartViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,  UITableViewDelegate {

var fromDetailFoodName: [String?] = []
var fromDetailFoodPrice =  Double()

var nameLabel = MyCartTableViewCell()

@IBOutlet weak var myCartTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var totalPriceLabel: UILabel!

let foodNames = [
    "Hamburger big mac",
    "Cemal",
    "Emre",
    "Memo"
]

//TODO-: Delete my cart
@IBAction func deleteMyCart(_ sender: Any) {
}

//TODO: - Approve my  cart
@IBAction func approveCart(_ sender: Any) {
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return section == 0 ? 1 : foodNames.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCartCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCartTableViewCell
    cell.myCartFoodNameLabel?.text = fromDetailFoodName.description
    cell.myCartFoodPriceLabel?.text = "\(fromDetailFoodPrice)₺"
    return cell
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the index path of the data you want to pass in `func addBasket(_ sender: Any)`.
For example, you can save index path as a property that referenced in class.

```
class StartViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

  var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
  }

  @IBAction func addBasket(_ sender: Any) {
    if let indexPath = selectedIndexPath {
      let destinationVC = MyCartViewController()
      destinationVC.detailFoodName = foodNames[indexPath.row]
      destinationVC.detailFoodPrice = foodPrices[indexPath.row].purchaseAmount
    }
  }
}
```

In `MyCartViewController` which is destination VC.

```
class MyCartViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,  UITableViewDelegate {

  var fromDetailFoodNames: [String?] = []
  var fromDetailFoodPrices:  [Double?] = []

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.last! <= fromDetailFoodPrices.indices.last! {
      let cell = myCartTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCartCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCartTableViewCell
      let name = fromDetailFoodNames[indexPath.row]?.description ?? ""
      let price = fromDetailFoodPrices[indexPath.row]
      cell.myCartFoodNameLabel?.text = name
      cell.myCartFoodPriceLabel?.text = "\(price)₺"
      return cell
    }
  }
}
```

BTW, for better coding, you can implement OOP concept in your code. detailFoodName and detailFoodPrice should be in ONE object. Besides, `var foodNameArray: String` naming could be confusing. Rename it as `var foodName: String` would be better.

Comment: If I add `destinationVC.detailFoodName = foodNames[indexPath.row]`. I am getting this error `Instance member 'detailFoodName' cannot be used on type 'DetailViewController'`

Comment: Sorry, edited. It should be `let destinationVC = DetailViewController()` rather then `let destinationVC = DetailViewController`.

Comment: So what can I do in my MyCartViewController ( which is my destination VC). I edit my question and add MyViewController codes.

Comment: You are best @Ciao I understand a lot with your route. This time I stuck in `prepare(for:segue:)` step. I am getting something like `Could not cast value of type 'UIButton' (0x10ebedfc0) to 'UITableViewCell'`

Comment: Yeah, the button's sender is UIButton, and it can't cast to the cell you touch. So in this case you have to save the index path.

Comment: I do not understand and not know how can I save the indexPath? It is so critical for `indexPath` action

Comment: What do you mean? You can save `indexPath` as I answered above. Do `selectedIndexPath = indexPath` in `didSelectRowAt:`. You must know which indexPath is selected by user, then save it.

Comment: `didSelectRowAt:` method is not about my button. I do not want pass the datas when user tap to table view cell. It should when user tap the button outside of `tableView`

Comment: Oh, if you don't need to pass the exact cell data that user select, just ignore the index save part. Pass all the names and prices array to destination VC directly.